# frog puzzle using strips and pddl

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

I've been trying to formalizing a domain and preparing two instances for a puzzle in which a frog is located in an n × n land, with few obstacles and a lot of insects. The frog can jump in any length in four cardinal directions and cannot land on any obstacles or already visited places. The frog eats insects whenever it lands on them. The goal is to eat all insects in the land. F denotes the initial location. The input corresponds to a n × n grid where F specifies the initial location of the frog, 0’s denote insects and 1’s denote obstacles. This requires planning (AI) but I'm new to strips, pddl and I'm stuck and can't figure out what to do. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You can find loads of examples in the [online editor](http://editor.planning.domains/) (use the import functionality), and that might help you get started on what the PDDL should look like.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.